# mysql count NULL

Tags: mysql, count, null

I have a game1 table,
it seems like this:

| player1 | player2 | result_1 | result_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | team2 | 10 | NULL |
| team1 | team3 | 10 | NULL |
| team2 | team3 | 6 | NULL |

result_1 is player1's result and result_2 is player2's result.

I want to make below table:

| player | count_null |
| --- | --- |
| team1 | 0 |
| team2 | 1 |
| team3 | 2 |

Please help me

Comment: Look into SQL GROUP BY if you want to come up with a solution on your own

Comment: what does the count_null column represent here? what is 0/1/2 for count_null ? is it by some custom logic or calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by "dividing" the table columns into more rows, then group by player (team) and then sum 1 when the result is null

```
SELECT player, sum(if(result is null, 1, 0))
FROM (
  SELECT player1 as player, result_1 as result
  FROM game1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT player2 as player, result_2 as result
  FROM game1) t
GROUP BY player
```

Comment: IF() is obviously excess, *`sum(if(result is null, 1, 0))`* can be replaced with `SUM(result IS NULL)`.